# Use sox to combine audios

Tags: ffmpeg, sox

I have three 3gp file,and I use sox to combine them

```
sox --combine sequence C:\1.3gp C:\2.3gp C:\3.3gp C:\newaudio.3gp
```

but It's show that "FAIL formats:no handler for file extension `3gp`"

Its means that I have to install some extension?

I'm trying to do it with sox,Can anybody give me any suggestions ?

Or It's possible do it with ffmpeg ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`3gp` is a multimedia container and not supported by `sox`.

You can extract the audio with `ffmpeg` and further process it with `sox` although `ffmpeg` can also do a lot of audio processing.

Here's one way to convert the data to `wav`, concatenate and convert back to `3gp`:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.3gp 1.wav
ffmpeg -i 2.3gp 2.wav
ffmpeg -i 3.3gp 3.wav
```

Concatenate, maybe other things with `sox` (sequence is default so no need to specify):

```
sox 1.wav 2.wav 3.wav long.wav
```

Convert back to `3gp`:

```
ffmpeg -i long.wav newaudio.3gp
```